# Request data from textbox returns null

Tags: php, laravel

Good day, i have a little problem, I'm new in laravel and i don't know what is causing this problem

i have a form
[image]

the code for the form is

```
<form action="/search">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <label>Search doctors, conditions or procedures</label>
                <input type="text" name="search_speciality" class="search_filter_textbox" placeholder="Speciality">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <label>For treatment near</label>
                <input type="text" name="search_speciality" class="search_filter_textbox" placeholder="City/ZIP Code">
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 search_filter_btn_wrapper">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info search_filter_btn">Search</button>
           </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my route

```
Route::get('/search', 'doctorController@search');
```

Here is my Controller

```
 public function search(Request $request){

    $textbox1 = $request->get('search_speciality');

    dd($textbox1);
}
```

i wanted to check if the request is working, but when i did this, the output was 
[image]

i displays null even though i inputted a data on the text which is "James" for this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two input fields with the same name `search_speciality`. Check through your code carefully. You need to change your code so it looks something like:

```html
<form action="/search">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <label>Search doctors, conditions or procedures</label>
                <input type="text" name="search_speciality" class="search_filter_textbox" placeholder="Speciality">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <label>For treatment near</label>
                <input type="text" name="search_city" class="search_filter_textbox" placeholder="City/ZIP Code">
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 search_filter_btn_wrapper">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info search_filter_btn">Search</button>
           </div>
    </div>
</form>
```